# set httponly flag to double parameter cookie in classic ASP

Tags: security, cookies, vbscript, asp-classic

I have double paramter cookies with below collection:

```
   Response.cookie("user")("id1") = "value1"
   Response.cookie("user")("id2") = "value2"
  Response.cookie("user")("id3") = "value3"
  Response.cookie("user")("id4") = "value4"
  Response.cookie("user")("id5") = "value5"
```

How do I set httponly true flag for cookie with "user" collection
How do I tweak below syntax to set http for double parameter cookie:

```
   Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie","user"; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Please advise

Comment: why do you need to "tweak" it? you're setting it correctly by using "user" for the cookies in question. do you not want it set to HttpOnly for every cookie?

Comment: Yes I need to set HttpOnly flag for all "user" cookie collection in classic ASP (vbscript). 

This syntax work fine if it is single parameter cookie
        e.g. Response.Cookie("user") = value 1  

But not working for double parameter cookie 
      e.g. response.cookie("user")("id1") = value1

It easy to implement in dotnet through web.config but not sure how to do it with classic ASP